# `gsub` for sentence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a string:

```
Тормозные диски
```

and with `gsub`, I must get:

```
+ТОРМОЗН* +ДИС*
```

I need to:

- Convert to uppercase (could do with `upcase`)
- At the beginning of a word,  add `+`
- For every word, slice the last two symbols
- At the last position, add `*`

It is hard for me to code all that are listed above. Help me, please.

Comment: Is it okay to use methods other than [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) on the string? I can imagine that it might help to also use other methods such as [`split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split), [`upcase`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-upcase), and [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map).

Comment: Hm, good question... Somebody's minus is not good here... Also try to add code, what you try. Maybe you get +1

Comment: Wanna look at persons, who minus me.

Comment: +1 for using split upcase and map. Gsub is messy for this stuff.

Comment: @injekt this is not reason to minus me... Try to help with map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `uppercase` because there is no such method in Ruby, but you can use `upcase` instead.

```
string.upcase.gsub(/\b(\w*?)\w{0,2}\b/, '+\1*')
```

Comment: @BorisStitnicky If your problem is with upcase, then perhaps that depends on the setting.

Comment: @sawa: He obviously has Cyrilic upcase problem. As you wrote it, it does not work out of the box when I try it on my machine. A short search told me that there is unicode_utils gem. If you know a way to upcase unicode chars without using this gem, please make it obvious.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky It does not matter if does not work on your machine. The OP describes of using upcase (mistaken as uppercase), and if it works on the OP's environment, it is fine.

Comment: @sawa: I think it does matter if it does not work on my machine, sorry for the opinion difference.

Comment: @brabertaser1992 I have nothing to say about `upcase` because you stated in the question that it works. As for the regex, if you are using Ruby 1.9 and UTF8, it should work. Otherwise, try replacing `\w` (and `\b`) with some character class (and its negation) from [here](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt).

Comment: @sawa i mean that .upcase.gsub(/\b(\w+?)\w{0,2}\b/, '+\1*')  didn't work, in log i get ... against ('Тормозной диск' in boolean mode) ...

Comment: @brabertaser1992: I gave you my hint. But I think that people are downvoting you because you did not show enough of your own effort.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky forget to say, pcase work only with .mb_chars.upcase

Answer (score 0):

I'll give a hint as to upcasing:

```
require "unicode_utils/upcase"
UnicodeUtils.upcase( 'Тормозные диски' )
```