# Add plus before first symbol in word in string and * after last

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dictionary, gsub

I have such string:

```
Тормозные диски
```

How can i transform it into

```
+Тормозн* +дис*
```

Now with help of SO i use gsub, but some people say that it could be done via map. But how? 
Note: main trouble is that i have cyrillic symbols...

now:

```
art_group_search = art_group.gsub(/\b(\w+?)\w{0,2}\b/, '+\1*').mb_chars.upcase.to_s
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [\`gsub\` for sentence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143992/gsub-for-sentence)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"Тормозные диски".split.map {|word| "+" + word + "*"}.join(" ")
```

To break that snippet up:

```
"Your string".split
=> ["Your", "string"]

["Your", "string"].map {|word| "+" + word + "*"}
=> ["+Your*", "+string*"]

["+Your*", "+string*"].join(" ")
=> "+Your* +string*"
```

Comment: @brabertaser1992 - I can't say I'm quite clear on what you did to fix your problem (or what your problem was precisely).

Comment: only when i write mb_chars.upcase